# I am trying to make a question bank with some options for each question

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, radio-button

I am making a question bank for storing questions. Each question has some options which some have correct and wrong options.

But the problem is that option text which I make is working fine but the option status (Correct/Wrong) which I am making through radio buttons is not correctly working. When I add one more option, the radio buttons are not working properly.

I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Basically I am making both as array types so, I loop it and get all values.

My code snippet

```js
removeThis();

$('#addMoreButton').on('click',function() {
  $('#addMoreHere').append('<div class="col-12 m-4 removeThis"><div class="form-group row text-left"><div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="questionOptionText">Option Text <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="questionOptionText" name="questionOptionText[]" required placeholder="Enter Option Text ex: xyz"></div> <span id="questionOptionText_error" class="removemsg text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="form-group col-md-4"> <label for="questionOptionStatus">Option Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label><div class="input-group"> <!-- 1 = Correct --> <div class="custom-control custom-radio"> <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="questionOptionShow" name="questionOptionStatus[]" required value="1"> <label class="custom-control-label" for="questionOptionShow">Correct</label> </div> <!-- 0 = Wrong --> <div class="custom-control custom-radio"><input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="questionOptionHide" name="questionOptionStatus" required value="0" checked> <label class="custom-control-label" for="questionOptionHide">Wrong</label> </div> </div> <span id="questionOptionStatus_error" class="removemsg text-danger"></span> </div> <div class="col-md-2 add_col" style="margin-top: 35px;"><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove This" class="btn btn-danger removeDiv" id="removeMoreButton"><b>-</b></button></div></div></div>');
 removeThis();
});

function removeThis() {
  $('.removeDiv').on('click',function() {
    $(this).parents('div.removeThis').remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 m-4">
  <div class="form-group row text-left">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="questionOptionText">Option Text <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="questionOptionText" name="questionOptionText[]" required placeholder="Enter Option Text ex: xyz">
      </div>
      <span id="questionOptionText_error" class="removemsg text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="questionOptionStatus">Option Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <!-- 1 = Correct -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="questionOptionShow" name="questionOptionStatus[]" required value="1">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="questionOptionShow">Correct</label>
        </div>
        <!-- 0 = Wrong -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="questionOptionHide" name="questionOptionStatus[]" required value="0" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="questionOptionHide">Wrong</label>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 add_col" style="margin-top: 35px;">
      <button type="button" title="Add More" class="btn btn-primary" id="addMoreButton"><b>+</b></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="addMoreHere"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With each click on the "Add more" button you're adding elements with the ids questionOptionText, questionOptionShow etc which you already have used before. But ids have to be unique. You might change the ids to class names instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each option you add uses the same ids and names, so it's getting confused.

You need to 'append' a dynamic result, not the same code each time.

So, not a complete example, but:

```
var number = 0; //for adding to IDs and names to make unique
$('#addMoreButton').on('click',function() {
  number++; //adds one so even if deleted a value, the number will still be unique
  var optionText = $('#questionOptionText').val(); //store the value
  $('#addMoreHere').append('<div><div class="form-group row text-left"><div class="form-group col-md-6"> <label for="questionOptionText' + number + '">Option Text <span class="text-danger">*</span></label> <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="questionOptionText' + number + '" name="questionOptionText[' + number + ']" required value="' + optionText + '"></div></div>');

});
```

Comment: @RajeevSingh Great! Please mark it as the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow